# Does there exist an integer $s$ such that every integer $> 1$ can be written as a sum of at most $s$ primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Does there exist an integer $s$ such that every integer $> 1$ can be written as a sum of at most $s$ primes ?

Comment: Yes.  See the discussion of rigorous results related to Goldbach's conjecture at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture and in particular Schnirelmann's constant.

Answer (score -1):

Terrence Tao has proven that [every odd number greater than one is the sum of at most five primes](http://fr.arxiv.org/abs/1201.6656). Hence, using $3$ as a prime that we can substract to any even number greater than $5$, and noticing that $2$ is prime and $4=2+2$, every odd number is the sum of at most six primes.

As a conclusion, every number greater than one is the sum of at most six primes.

Of course, this is a very loose approximation. If it is proven, Goldbach's conjecture would allow us to lower the number of needed primes to $3$.